# Using @WebFault for JAX-WS exception handling

Tags: java, exception, jax-ws

I am trying to use the @WebFault annotation and I have a web service that can throw several exceptions such as the following example class MyException1.

Following the examples from http://java.globinch.com/enterprise-java/web-services/jax-ws/jax-ws-exceptions-faults-annotation-exception-and-fault-handling-examples/ I coded each exception like MyException1 and all the MyException[N] classes are similar: they have a private member which is the Fault POJO/bean and constructors.

How can I avoid copy pasting N classes like this which only differ in the class name?  I can't define a base class and subclass each exception because they can't inherit the constructors.

```
@WebFault(name="ServiceFault",targetNamespace="http://somenamespace.com")
public class MyException1 extends Exception {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ServiceFault fault;

    public MyException1(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ServiceFault getFault() {
        return fault;
    }

    public MyException1() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyException1(String message, Throwable cause,
            boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
        super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyException1(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyException1(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public MyException1(ServiceFault fault) {
        super(fault.getFaultString());
        this.fault = fault;
    }

    public MyException1(String message, ServiceFault fault) {
        super(message);
        this.fault = fault;
    }

    public MyException1(String message, ServiceFault fault,
            Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.fault = fault;
    }

    public MyException1(String code, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.fault = new ServiceFault();
        this.fault.setFaultCode(code);
        this.fault.setFaultString(message);
    }

}

... and similarly for MyException2, ..., MyExceptionN
```

Comment: DO the fault POJO's differ in each of your exception classes?

Comment: No, it's the same class.

Comment: Why not a generic exception name(just one exception class) and granular details in the ServiceFault POJO?

Comment: The services I am exposing return several error codes and I read somewhere it is a good practice to use exceptions instead of error codes. That is why I decided to create an Exception class for each error in the exposed API.

Comment: It seems like what you're asking is "How do I create multiple classes without creating multiple classes?"  I think your best bet here is to go with the suggestion @Abhin gave; you're still using an exception (and avoiding checking the return value for error codes), but you're also preserving the error codes so you can decide what to do with any given exception in a `catch` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:-

1) Either have a parent `MyWSException` *having a* `ServiceFault` POJO extended by child exception classes having names representing exceptions that occur in your service.

2) Have a generic `MyWSException` class with details encapsulated in `ServiceFault` POJO .